# put the word "suggestions" in autocomplete box just like google

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want put the word "suggestions" in autocomplete box just like google does. How do I do that? Here is my auto complete page http://www.maxihealth.com/test/autocomplete.html